# Python Requests getting final link

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I know I am probably going about this the wrong way. But i am trying to figure out what resource URL's in our proxy server config are broken or redirecting to a different URL than what we have on file.

An example of a resource being passed into out proxy prefix URL is:

```
https://login.proxy.library.ohio.edu/login?auth=ou&url=https://www.whatismyip.com/
```

When this URL is resolved it should redirect to the proxied link

```
https://www-whatismyip-com.proxy.library.ohio.edu/
```

What I am wanting is to get the final status code of the final URL after it is resolved and redirected

What I have code wise, just a snippet...

```
proxy_url = "https://login.proxy.library.ohio.edu/login?auth=ou&url=https://www.whatismyip.com/"
conn = requests.head(proxy_url, allow_redirects=True)
print conn.url[:-3]
```

The [:-3] is to remove some weird unwanted characters at the end of the string.

However it is only returning the original link I am passing it.
How can I get the correct proxied URL after it's resolved and redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history` property of the [Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) object to track redirection:

```
resp = requests.head("http://some.url", allow_redirects=True)
for elem in resp.history:
    print elem.url  # "some_other.url"
```

`Response.history` contains all responses with their urls from intermediate steps. Read more [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

Comment: I tried that just a minute ago. The list comes back as empty, like it is just stopping at that page and not fully resolving it.

Comment: Tried your url, it returns 200 status. Why do you think it has to be redirected?

Comment: Stupid me, that one was not one originally redirecting. 

https://login.proxy.library.ohio.edu/login?auth=ou&url=http://adage.com/portal/2sGAAHI8ro

That one was

Comment: Here is the thing: your original url `login.proxy.library` returns 200 status and some html+js code. That js code performs redirect. Since `request` doesn't have any js engine inside, there is no redirect. Browsers have js engine and perform redirects correctly.

Comment: You can test using selenium if js is required